# What does the sim_time mean?

Tags: navigation, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello , every earnest folk

The question what headline states has confused me a long time . I can't understand that parameter's meaning. I have seen introduction from [here](http://wiki.ros.org/base_local_planner) many times ,But it still puzzles me .In my opinion ,`sim_granularity` and `vx_sample` have decided the distance should be forward_simulated .So ,what does the sim_time mean ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/153616/what-does-the-sim_time-mean-?/) by [zsbhaha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13451/zsbhaha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2014-04-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In [this github page,](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/tree/jade-devel/base_local_planner)
include/base_local_planner/trajectory_planner.h:

```
@param sim_time The number of seconds to "roll-out" each trajectory
```

---

Originally posted by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) with karma: 856 on 2015-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0